# Help with a Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis

Given the function g:[0,1]->R: g(x)=0 if 0$\le$x$\le$$\frac{1}{2}$,g(x)=1 if $\frac{1}{2}$$\lt$x$\le$1. Prove that f es g- integrable in [0,1] if and only if  f is continuos from the right in $\frac{1}{2}$. In this case the value of the integral is f($\frac{1}{2}$).

Any insight is helpful :)

Comment: This seems to be a popular question. [Already asked about an hour ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928404/showing-f-is-riemann-integrable-with-respect-to-g).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, this is wrong.

Take:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\sin \left(\frac{1}{1/2-x}\right) & \text{if } 0 \le x \lt 1/2\\
0 & \text{if } 1/2 \le x \le 1
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is bounded and right continuous at $1/2$. However, you can find a sequence of partitions $\{P_n\}$ whose norms approach zero and for which $S(P_n,f,g) = (-1)^n$.